# Check if string exists in HTML table using VbScript

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Hi I am new to HPE UFT testing and I'd like to write a VBscript. 
This is my HTML Table:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed data-table dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
   <thead>
      <tr role="row">
         <th tabindex="0" class="sorting" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="width: 226px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Name</th>
         <th tabindex="0" class="sorting" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="width: 481px;" aria-label="Address: activate to sort column ascending" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Address</th>
         <th tabindex="0" class="sorting" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" style="width: 138px;" aria-label="VAT Number: activate to sort column ascending" rowspan="1" colspan="1">VAT Number</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" style="width: 64px;" aria-label="&amp;nbsp;" rowspan="1" colspan="1" data-orderable="false">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="odd" role="row">
         <td>myCompany</td>
         <td>test street, USA, WD</td>
         <td>65465465465464</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even" role="row">
         <td>Supplier</td>
         <td>Franklin Street, USA, NYC</td>
         <td>654564654654</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Id like to write a function or procedure to loop through the table and check if the string **myCompany** does exist in the table body.
The test scenario is accepted if the specific Company Name is shown in the result list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 IntRowNum=Browser("CreationTime:=0").Page("name:=myPage").WebTable("name:=myTable").getRowWithCellText("myCompany")
```

IntRowNum is -1 if the text is not found. Otherwise the rownumber is returned.